# CakePHP Bake PHP Version Error

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using Hostgator for hosting to start, I have the file location of the website set to `public_html\WebsiteName\Public` (where public is the directory for the CakePHP.

I am trying to run `bin/Cake bake` and I receive the following error:

Minimum PHP version: 5.6. You are using: 5.4.45.

I have verified that the all the directories leading up to and including the CakePHP folders are 7.0 or 5.6. When I do a php -v i get version PHP 5.6.30 in all those folders as well.

Is there anything I can do to choose what version cake bake uses? What might I be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is your webserver problem. 
There is nothing to do with cake bake.

Find a way to configure which php version that you have to use.